# When Dialog is displayed, How ignore touch event the View on the back of Dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

When Dialog is displayed, How ignore touch event the View on the back of Dialog?
I use the Dialog view.

Comment: i think, setting a flag variable might help u...

Comment: You just use modal dialog that will avoid user touch background

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. it might help u...

```
<view_in_the_back>.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    if(flag==true){
                 //code of this touch event...
         return true;
            }  
}
});
```

set flag=false when the dialog is shown. set to true one its been dismissed.